# The group $G$ is Abelian iff every irreducible character is linear.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$\textbf{The question is as follows:}$

> The group $G$ is Abelian if and only if every irreducible character of $G$ is linear.

Here there is a nice and short proof for this, but there are some assertions which I cannot understand.

There are identical questions here [link to the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616114/a-direct-proof-that-for-finite-g-we-have-g-abelian-iff-all-irreducible-char) and [link to the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612209/show-that-the-group-g-is-abelian-if-and-only-if-every-irreducible-character-of). But the  proof which comes is shorter.

> > Let $k$ be the number of conjugacy classes of $G$. Then $k = |G|$ if and only if $G$ is Abelian.
> >
> > Now $|G| = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \chi_{i}^{2}(1)$ and $\chi_i(1)\ge 1$ for all $i$. It follows then $k = |G|$ if and only if $\chi_i(1) = 1$ for all $i$.

$\textbf{First:}$ Why it is true that " $k = |G|$ if and only if $G$ is Abelian?"

$\textbf{Second:}$ How did he conclude the result?

Can somone please explain it to me?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A group is abelian if and only if every element commutes with every other element.

If an element belongs to a conjugacy class of size $1$ it commutes with every other element because $b^{-1}ab=a$ implies that $ab=ba$

If an element belongs to a conjugacy class of size greater than $1$ you have an equation $b^{-1}ab=c$ with $a\neq c$ and $ab=bc\neq ba$ so the group is not abelian.

In an abelian group, therefore, all conjugacy classes have size $1$, and if the group is not abelian $ab=bc\neq ba$ implies that $a$ and $c$ are in the same conjugacy class, which doesn't have size $1$.

---

For the second part, the arithmetic is done with characters, and characters belong to their associated representations. I assume you are working over $\mathbb C$ (an algebraically closed field).

Then, simply, it is a theorem of representation theory that the number of irreducible representations (characters) is equal to the number of conjugacy classes. So for an abelian group, this is the same as the number of elements.

Also the sum of the squares of the degrees of the representations (characters) is equal to the order of the group, so in the abelian case none of the representations can have order greater than $1$. And if there are fewer representations than elements of $G$, some representation must have order greater than $1$, and there will be a conjugacy class containing more than one element so the group will not be abelian.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: Many thanks! But can you please write me down that which part of your answer gives an answer to the $\textbf{First}$ question? I think all your answer is related to the $\textbf{Second}$ question? Can you please separate them? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Nikita I have added some comments on that, but am not sure what your problem is, so don't quite know whether this is helpful.

Comment: Many thanks for your time! I mean can you please fill in the dashed space in what I write below by your answer and then rewrite your answer again? "Let $k$ be the number of conjugacy classes of $G$. Then $k = |G|$ if and only if $G$ is Abelian, because $______$<p>
Now $|G| = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \chi_{i}^{2}(1)$ and $\chi_i(1)\ge 1$ for all $i$. It follows then $k = |G|$ if and only if $\chi_i(1) = 1$ for all $i$, because $________$. "<p> Many thanks!

Comment: @Nikita Because in a non-abelian group there is a conjugacy class of size greater than $1$, and in an abelian group every element is conjugate only with itself. Because a sum of squares of $k$ positive integers is greater than or equal to $k$ and equality holds only if the squares are all equal to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

All the conjugacy classes in an Abelian group have size $1$.

In a non-Abelian group, if $ab\ne ba$, then $ab$ and $ba$ are conjugate,
so you have a conjugacy class of size $>1$. So the number of conjugacy
classes is $<|G|$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!